# Invalid Tilemap Layer ID

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

I was doing my game in phaser 3 when I went to add a tilemap created in tiled, I followed several tutorials, I did and redid the code several times and even then it always gives me the same invalid ID error.

**unsuccessful attempts:**

- Tried to manually make the tilemap;
- Tried using JSON files;
- I tried to use a single layer;
- I tried to use the names according to the tiled layers;
- I tried using different names;

here follows the code:

```
import './phaser'

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: "phaser-example",
  width: 1824,
  height: 960,
  physics: {
      default: 'arcade'
  },
  scene: {
      preload: preload,
      create: create
  }
};

export const game = new Phaser.Game(config)

function preload()
{
  this.load.image('terrain', './complementos/tilemaps/terrainBasic.png')
  this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', './complementos/tilemaps/basicLand.json')
}

function create()
{
  const teste = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]
  
  const map = this.make.tilemap(teste)

  map.addTilesetImage('terrainBasic','terrain', 32, 32)
  
  const layer = map.createLayer(0,'land', 0, 0)
}
```

I don't know if it changes much but I was using react together with phaser 3, but my react code only had styling.

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your question or try [pt.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your are not providig the correct parameters for the `tilemap` function. You have to pass a `Phaser.Tilemaps.MapData` checkout the documentation, here https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html or you could checkout the examples on the phaser.io website.

Checkout especially, some Demos on the official website, they show many different ways how to use tiles(maps) *(with working examples)*: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/tilemap

**Here is a snippet, showing how to use a array, for the tiles:**

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 5*16,
    height: 3*16,
    zoom:2,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/super-mario.png');
}

function create ()
{
    // Load a map from a 2D array of tile indices
    var level = [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[ 0, 14, 13, 14, 0],[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

    var map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    var tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    var layer = map.createLayer(0, tiles, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```